# PHP repeat SQL entry X amount of times

Tags: php

I have an ecommerce store I am setting up and I need every item purchased entered in the database. For example, someone purchases a qty of 2, I need to repeat the SQL data entry so it has two entries. See code below and let me know how I can use product_qty to achieve this.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]))
{
    $total = 0; //set initial total value
    $b = 0; //var for zebra stripe table 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
        $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
        $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
        $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
        $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
        $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); //calculate Price x Qty
        $name = $_SESSION['firstName']. ' ' .$_SESSION['lastName']; 

        mysqli_query(
            $mysqli,
            "INSERT INTO Order_Tickets 
                    (sku, tktproduct, tktprice, purchaser)
             VALUES ('$product_code','$product_name','$product_price','$name')"
        ) or die(mysqli_error());
    }

}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Yes, I know, this is early development, that will get added in once I have a functioning code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this?

```
if ($product_qty > 1)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $product_qty; $i++)
    {
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Order_Tickets (sku, tktproduct, tktprice, purchaser) VALUES ('$product_code','$product_name','$product_price','$name')") 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You put me on the right track - just one change needed $i has to equal 1 and not zero